# How to best assign predicted k-means clusters to original data

Tags: sparklyr

I am doing ml_kmeans analysis using sparklyr.

My question is how best to assign the predicted cluster memberships. The comments in the code on github mention returned data.frames from ml_kmeans may not be ordered properly.

So far I have come up with the following solution, but it seems a bit verbose, is there a better way to merge the predicted cluster memberships with the original data?

I would love to use broom package but I don't think ml_kmeans is supported.

```
# load lib and connect
  library(sparklyr)

# connect
  sc <- spark_connect( master = "local" )

# compute id column
  iris <- iris %>% 
          mutate( id = row_number()-1 ) 

# copy to spark
  iris_tbl  <- sdf_copy_to( sc, iris, overwrite = TRUE )

# compute kmeans
  iris_kmeans <- iris_tbl %>% 
                  select( -id,-Species) %>% # remove non relevant columns
                  ml_kmeans( centers = 5L,
                             init_mode = "k-means||"
                            ) 

# assign cluster membership
  iris_cluster <- sdf_predict( iris_kmeans, 
                               new_data = "iris_tbl" ) %>% 
                  compute( "iris_cluster" )

# extract id column
  id_col <- iris_kmeans$ml.options$id.column

# bind columns and collect results
  iris_result <- cluster_membership  %>% 
                  sdf_sort( id_col ) %>% # sort by assigned spark id
                  select( prediction, id_col ) %>% # select cols to be merged
                  sdf_bind_cols( iris_tbl ) %>% 
                  collect( 'iris_result' )
```

Answer (score 1):

With the latest dev (as soon as [sparklyr/pull/1218](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/pull/1218) is merged) you can do something like

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
iris_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, iris)
iris_kmeans <- ml_kmeans(iris_tbl, ~ . - Species, centers = 5)
ml_predict(iris_kmeans, iris_tbl)
# alternatively
sdf_predict(iris_tbl, iris_kmeans)
```

Note that you need to pass a (one-sided) formula or `features` to `ml_kmeans()` to let it know which variables you want to cluster with. The `ml_predict()` and `sdf_predict()` functions do the same thing, just with different ordering of arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and immediate action. This is indeed way more convenient. Great.